# Heroku attempts to push to a different directory

Tags: heroku

Can anyone tell my why I get this error when I try to push to Heroku

```
fatal: http://mbartonsampleapp.heroku.com//info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Why has this been added to my directory `//info/refs` 
I want to go to http://mbartonsampleapp.heroku.com. Is there a way I can change my directory back down So that Heroku will know where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can push to Heroku via HTTP. You should have a `git:` URL to push to (which should've been set up when you ran created the app using the Heroku command-line tool).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was using `git push heroku ` and then this error occured.

Comment: <SOLVED> had to re add using `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:{my-project-name}.git `